# Identical buffered images in a set

Tags: java

Should the following set contain duplicates?

```
HashSet<BufferedImage> digitsIncaptcha = new HashSet<>();
digitsIncaptcha.add(digit);
```

While adding images to the set I expect that there will not be identical images there, but they are. When I save to disk the content of `digitsIncaptcha` there are identical occurenses, i.e. the same size, the same dimentions and the same pixel by pixel color.

Comment: [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) does not override equals, so two instances are only equal if they are the same instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hence the BufferedImage doesn't override the hashCode and equals methods from the Object class, you will get duplicates in the set.

I personally never worked with BufferedImage instances, but I'd create a wrapper class, which contains the BufferedImage and it lazily calculates a hashCode and equals according to the data in the BufferedImage and use it for duplicate elimination.